# Improving for and while zgrep search

Tags: bash

I have a list of 18 digit strings that I want to zgrep from the logs. The way I use it now is that the scripts takes a string, zgreps the logs(logs are saved by the hour) and runs with it. The issue is that it takes a long time and I wanted help with improving it.

```
do while read x ;
do echo $x && zgrep $x /logs/location/app*2019$y* ;
done < file_$y > logs_$y ;
done
```

I had an idea that the script would take 8 digits and insert them into zgrep location `/app*HERE$y*`

Comment: `grep` has `-f` option.

Comment: If you want to search compressed logs for `a` or `b` or `c`, rather than decompress 3 times and search for one letter each time, you could decompress and search just once for any of them with `zgrep -E 'a|b|c' logs*`

Answer (score 1):

Quick hack: I think you could replace that whole inner loop with one quick `sed` and one `zgrep`.

```
for y in {files} 
do zgrep -f list_$y $( sed  -E 's,(.*),/location/app*20\1*,' list_$y )
done
```

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up with the following script that met my needs and worked great:

```
for y in {files} ;
do while read x ;
do echo $x && z=/location/app*20"${x:0:8}"* && zgrep $x $z ;
done < list_$y > logs_$y ;
done ;
```